# SQLAlchemy: how to work with month intervals using timedelta

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table in PostgreSQL with `interval` field. There is a possibility that someone may want to store something like `INTERVAL '1 MONTH'` in this table. In my Python application, I have a `timedelta` object which is substituted to a query string:

```
with sqla_engine.connect() as conn:
    # 'params' contains parametrised SQL where one of the fields is a timedelta object 
    return conn.execute(text(query).execution_options(autocommit=autocommit), params)
```

I want to replace my `timedelta` object with something that is translated as `INTERVAL '1 MONTH'` by SQLAlchemy Engine. Is that possible?

And, in reverse, how can I read `interval '1 month'` value from PostgreSQL into something usable in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace my `timedelta` object with something that is translated as `INTERVAL '1 MONTH'` by SQLAlchemy Engine. Is that possible?

PostgreSQL accepts string values for `interval` columns so this works:

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Table,
    MetaData,
    Column,
    Integer,
    text,
    Interval,
)

engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test", echo=True
)

tbl = Table(
    "tbl",
    MetaData(),
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    Column("intrvl", Interval()),
)
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)
"""SQL emitted:
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    intrvl INTERVAL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), {"id": 1, "intrvl": "1 MONTH"})
    """SQL emitted:
    2021-03-29 17:32:27,427 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO tbl (id, intrvl) VALUES (%(id)s, %(intrvl)s)
    2021-03-29 17:32:27,428 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00032s] {'id': 1, 'intrvl': '1 MONTH'}
    """
```

and if we query the table from `psql` we can see that the value has been stored:

```
gord@gord-dv7-xubuntu0:~$ psql -h 192.168.0.199 test scott
Password for user scott: 
psql (12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-1.pgdg18.04+1), server 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

test=# select * from tbl;
 id | intrvl 
----+--------
  1 | 1 mon
(1 row)
```

> And, in reverse, how can I read `interval '1 month'` value from PostgreSQL into something usable in Python?

psycopg2 will return the value as a timedelta, but timedelta does not support `months=` so it just assumes 30 days:

```py
    results = conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM tbl")).fetchall()
    print(results)
    # [(1, datetime.timedelta(days=30))]
```

**Update:**

> Is there a way to make a correct transformation, translate it into string value "1 month" for example?

Your SQL query could ask for `cast(intrvl as varchar(50)) as intrvl_str` to get back a string, and if you wanted to make that automatic you could define `intrvl_str` as a `Computed` (generated) column in the table:

```py
tbl = Table(
    "tbl",
    MetaData(),
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    Column("intrvl", Interval()),
    Column("intrvl_str", String(50), Computed("cast (intrvl as varchar(50))")),
)
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)
"""SQL emitted:
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    intrvl INTERVAL, 
    intrvl_str VARCHAR(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast (intrvl as varchar(50))) STORED, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), {"id": 1, "intrvl": "1 MONTH"})
    """SQL emitted: (same as before)
    2021-03-29 17:32:27,427 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO tbl (id, intrvl) VALUES (%(id)s, %(intrvl)s)
    2021-03-29 17:32:27,428 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00032s] {'id': 1, 'intrvl': '1 MONTH'}
    """

    results = conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM tbl")).fetchall()
    print(results)
    # [(1, datetime.timedelta(days=30), '1 mon')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, the second is incorrect for obvious reasons. For my task it's not possible to assume that each month contains 30 days. Is there a way to make a correct transformation, translate it into string value "1 month" for example?

Comment: So if I use SQLA's `Interval` I must use plain text SQL? Could I pass a Python's `timedelta` object?